# Error on Default.aspx.designer.cs after concatenating a for loop variable in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net web form Default.aspx.

In javascript I have built this function:

```
function removeAndAddPermisionsRows(table, accesses) {
    deleteRows(table);

    var accessesLen = accesses.length;
    var row = '<tr>';

    for (var i = 0; i < accessesLen; i++) {
        if (i != 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
            row = row + '</tr><tr>';
        }

        row = row +
            '    <td class="leftMarginSectionItem">' +
            '        <asp:Image ID="PermisionImgSectionItem" runat="server" Width="32px" Height="32px" ImageUrl="~/Images/checkmark32.png" />' +
            '    </td>' +
            '    <td>' +
            '        <div>' +
            '            <h3 id="PermisionSectionItem"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPermission" Text=""></asp:Label></h3>' +
            '            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPermissionId" Text=""></asp:Label>' +
            '        </div>' +
            '        <p id="permisionRect" class="roundedCornersRectangleSectionItemsBackground" />' +
            '    </td>';
    }

    if (accessesLen % 2 == 0) {
        row = row + '</tr>';
    }
    else {
        row = row + '<td></td><td></td></tr>';
    }

    table.find('tbody').append(row);
}
```

Ok, no problem here, this code compiles ok.

But I need to concatenate the "i" variable from the loop to some strings so If for example I do below within the loop, for example I want the ID PermisionImgSelectionItem to be PermisionImgSelectionItem0, PermisionImgSelectionItem1, and so on, the same for the rest of IDs:

```
        row = row +
            '    <td class="leftMarginSectionItem">' +
            '        <asp:Image ID="PermisionImgSectionItem'+ i +'" runat="server" Width="32px" Height="32px" ImageUrl="~/Images/checkmark32.png" />' +
            '    </td>' +
            '    <td>' +
            '        <div>' +
            '            <h3 id="PermisionSectionItem"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPermission" Text=""></asp:Label></h3>' +
            '            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPermissionId" Text=""></asp:Label>' +
            '        </div>' +
            '        <p id="permisionRect" class="roundedCornersRectangleSectionItemsBackground" />' +
            '    </td>';
```

When I concatenate the i variable to the string my code does not compile, vs2019 says there is an error in the automatically generated Default.aspx.designer.cs, I have no idea but it concatenates as well the variable "i" to the name of some controls.

What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by asp:Label element. Conactenating this element within a string and loop variables cause this error! Replacing asp:Label by simply an html label solves the problem.